# Change the "Master" name on Hudson

Tags: hudson

Is there any way to change the "master" node name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- Set  the number of executors to 0 in the "System Configuration"
- Create a slave node in the master server and assigned a proper name for it

This solved my problem of having an unwanted "master" name in the list of slave nodes. The cost is to have two java processes running on the master server: one for hudson itself and another for the slave node.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the Master node behaves just like any other node.  You can click on the node, then change the "name" field to whatever you like.

We connect via JNLP.  So, we also need to make sure that the JNLP service and Hudson are looking for the same name.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? If I go to the node master and click the config link, it gives me the "Manage Hudson"->config page and not a node config page.